# write output of dvips to a file

Tags: auxiliary-files, dvips, unix

Sorry if this is a simple question.

I want to write the output of `dvips` to a file  (i.e. something like a log file for `dvips`). I tried this but it gives an empty file:

```
dvips input.dvi > dvipslog.txt
```

My operating system is GNU/Linux CentOS 5.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The messages are sent by dvips to stderr. So try `dvips input.dvi >& dvipslog.txt`, which works for bash.

If you just want to get rid of the messages, use `dvips -q`.